# Delegados C# ayuda

Tags: c#

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio

```
/*
Defina el delegado PrecioCambiadoEventHandler, la clase PrecioCambiadoEventArgs y la clase Articulo
de tal forma que el programa siguiente genere la siguiente salida por consola
   Articulo 1 valia 0 y ahora vale 10
   Articulo 1 valia 10 y ahora vale 12
   Articulo 1 valia 12 y ahora vale 14
 */



using System;


class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Articulo a = new Articulo();
        a.PrecioCambiado += new PrecioCambiadoEventHandler(precioCambiado);
        a.Codigo = 1;
        a.Precio = 10;
        a.Precio = 12;
        a.Precio = 12;
        a.Precio = 14;
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

public static void precioCambiado(object sender, PrecioCambiadoEventArgs e){
    string texto = "Artículo {0} valía {1} y ahora vale {2}";
    Console.WriteLine(texto,e.Codigo,e.PrecioAnterior,e.PrecioNuevo);
  }
}
```

La clase Articulo cuenta con las propiedades de lectura/escritura Codigo y Precio. Además posee el evento PrecioCambiado que se produce cuando se cambia el valor de la propiedad Precio (observe que si se asigna el mismo valor el evento no se produce).

yo hice esto de acá abajo. pero no entiendo bien los delegados

```
class PrecioCambiadoEventArgs:EventArgs {

public int Codigo{
    get{return Codigo;}
    set{Codigo = value;}
}
public double PrecioAnterior{
    get{return PrecioAnterior;}
    set{PrecioAnterior = value;}
}
public double PrecioNuevo{
    get{return PrecioNuevo;}
    set{PrecioNuevo = value;}   
}

public PrecioCambiadoEventArgs(int codigo, double precioAnterior, double precioNuevo){
    this.Codigo = codigo;
    this.PrecioAnterior = precioAnterior;
    this.PrecioNuevo = precioNuevo;
}
}


class Articulo {
/*  posee el evento PrecioCambiado que se produce cuando se cambia el valor de la propiedad Precio
(observe que si se asigna el mismo valor el evento no se produce).*/


private int cod;
private double pre;

public Articulo(){

}


public void PrecioCambiadoEventHandler PrecioCambiado (object sender, PrecioCambiadoEventArgs e) {

    }




public int Codigo{
    get{
        return cod; 
    }
    set{
        cod = value;
    }
}

public double Precio{
    get{
        return pre;
    }
    set{
        double pre = value;
        //Llamar al Evento aca?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Deberías usar la interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

Mas info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Acá hay un ejemplo bastante claro: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: hola. los enlaces no son bien vistos porque se terminan cayendo y no se pueden arreglar. Si crees que hay informacion relevante para que OP resuelva el problema, por favor copiala en tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si. lo que estas pensando es lo correcto.

Debes generar un objeto que contenga los parámetros, y después llamar al evento exactamente donde lo piensas. 
Algo asi como :

```
PrecioCambiadoEventArgs p = new PrecioCambiadoEventArgs(Codigo, pre, value)
```

y luego llamar al evento

```
PrecioCambiado (this, p)
```

Recorda que como dice por ahí, tenes que tener cuidado de no llamarlo si el precio en realidad no cambio.

Igual el problema que veo, es que en ningun momento estas definiendo un evento. Sin un handler para el mismo, pero y el evento?